# Blank admin page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, admin

Is it possible to make a page in wordpress that you can open in a new window, but without any of the admin panels?

This could be useful for printing of sensitive data. How could this be done ?

it would be necessary to be able to test against the `if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ... }` however.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new .php file in your root folder or wherever you like and do something like this:

```
<?php

define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

//DO SOMETHING

}

?>
```

This will give you your blank page, and with all the available WordPress functionality to use.

Comment: Thank you so much! it seems to work even without the define statement.

Comment: Could there be a safer way to make the path for wp-load.php, in case the user havent installed wordpress in the root folder? would be prefer not going relative though.

Comment: you could use require(get_bloginfo('url') . '/wp-load.php'); or something similar

Comment: would i have access to that function before its loaded?